# localtunnel don't generate url to google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, streamlit, localtunnel

On google colab I installed streamlit, created a simple app.py and try to use localtunnel to test it but the localtunnel link did not appear.
The code I used was:

First:

```
! pip install streamlit -q
```

After:

```
%%writefile app.py
import streamlit as st
st.write('# test')
```

Finally:

```
!streamlit run /content/app.py & npx localtunnel --port 8501
```

The result should show the localtunnel url but just show that:

2022-07-15 19:26:00.602 INFO    numexpr.utils: NumExpr defaulting to 2 threads.

You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

Network URL: http://172.28.0.2:8501
External URL: http://35.196.140.5:8501

npx: installed 22 in 4.802s

Answer (score -1):

try streamlit in the previous version it works good with me

! pip install streamlit==1.13.0 -q

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33430204)